# Issue when passing std::function as a parameter

Tags: c++, clang, std-function

I'm having this strange issue (I've simplified the code here) with clang 3.1 (gcc works fine).
Is it improper use of std::function (passed by value) or a clang bug?

```
template <typename Container>
struct A
{
  using function_type = std::function<char(char)>;

  A(Container c, function_type f) : it_(c.begin()), f_(f) {}
  typename Container::value_type operator*() { return *it_; }

  typename Container::iterator it_;
  function_type f_;
};

template <typename Cont>
A<Cont> makeA(Cont c, std::function<char(char)> f)
{
  return A<Cont>(c, f);
}

char f(char ch) { return ch; }

int main()
{
  std::string s { "foo" };
  auto a = makeA(s, f); // wraps s.begin()
  std::clog << "main: " << *(s.begin()) << std::endl; // prints 'f'
  std::clog << "main: " << *a << std::endl; // prints garbage
  return 0;
}
```

I'm using Apple clang 4.1 (llvm 3.1) on Max OS X Lion.

If I change the type of the second parameter to something else (such as int), everything works fine.

If I construct the A object directly from the ctor, instead of using the 'make' factory, everything works fine.

I really can't understand whether it's a clang bug or my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the `string` by value in to the constructor of `A`, and then creating an iterator in to the local string. The string is then destroyed at the end of the constructor, leaving you with an invalid iterator and undefined behavior.

```
//`c` is a local copy of the string
A(Container c, function_type f) :
    //c.begin() returns an iterator into `c`
    it_(c.begin()),
    f_(f)
{
}//`c` is destroyed, leaving it_ as a dangling iterator

//Dereferences `it_` -- undefined behaviour
typename Container::value_type operator*() { return *it_; }
```